# regex: Select all lines that do not end with a specific tag

Tags: windows-10, notepad++, regex

I have this 4 lines, all starting with tag `<p class="TEST">` and ending with tag `<br>` except the last two.

```
<p class="TEST">My mother is at home.<br>
<p class="TEST">My father is at home.<br>
<p class="TEXT">My sister is at home.<LLbr>
<p class="TEXT">My brother is at home.<AAbr>
```

So, I want to find all lines with TEXT tag that doesn't ending with `<br>`

My output result should be

```
<p class="TEXT">My sister is at home.<LLbr>
<p class="TEXT">My brother is at home.<AAbr>
```

I made a regex, but is not too good. 
`(?-s)(.*<p class="TEXT">.*)(?-s)(?!)<br>(.*)$`

Comment: One option, that might give you what you want.  If you Ctrl-F to bring up the search dialog, then click on the Mark tab.  Check the Bookmark line option and search for <br> or whatever you need to mark the line.  Then go to Search - Bookmark and select inverse bookmark.  I find this workflow helpful in many scenarios. Hope it helps.

Comment: I have more than 5000 .html files to check :) I don't have time to check each individually :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `<p class="TEXT">(?:(?!<br>)(?!<p).)*(?:<.+?>|\z)`
- *UNcheck Match case*
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *UNCHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Search in document</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
<p class="TEXT">    # literally
(?:                 # start non capture group
  (?!<br>)          # negative lookahead, make sure we haven't <br>
  (?!<p)            # negative lookahead, make sure we haven't <p
  .                 # any character but newline
)*                  # group may appear 0 or more times
(?:                 # non capture group
   <.+?>            # a tag
 |                  # OR
   \z               # end of string
)                   # end of group
```

[image]

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vSfrsv/3)

Comment: hello Toto, thanks a lot. But, another scenario.Suppose  the `<br>` tag is on the next line, and I don't want to find also this because has <br>. See this link https://regex101.com/r/vSfrsv/2/

Comment: @JustMe: [See updated demo](https://regex101.com/r/vSfrsv/3)

Comment: thank you, Toto. Please, update your answer with this alternative regex solution here, in case anyone need it. And also, please explain what means this part of regex:  (?!<p).)*(?:<.+?>|\z)

Comment: @JustMe: edit done.

Comment: please see this real case.  https://regex101.com/r/y8GB6e/1  I change a little bit your regex, with my real tags. But is not working. Please help me, and change the good version on the link below. Instead of <br> I have  </p>

Comment: @JustMe: Have a try with https://regex101.com/r/y8GB6e/2 but please, stop changing question in comment. I suggest you give real test cases that covert all your special cases in a new question.

Comment: yes, I can open another topic, but if I do this, I believe my account here will be restricted forever. They will say I made it purposeful. Anyway, forgive me, it is very late here. In my preview link, I forgot to write a line. Can you please update (for the last time) your regex.  https://regex101.com/r/y8GB6e/5

Comment: @JustMe: I've just tested it with Notepad++ and it works fine even if it doesn't work on regex101

Comment: not quite, also in notepad++ your last regex selects the last line (that shoulnd't) because is followed by </p>

Comment: @JustMe: You're right, my bad. I've tested with `class="TEST"`. But now the regex becomes too complex.  suggest you to do in two steps. 1- remove the linebreak before tags `find: \R<`, `Replace with: <`. 2- run the previous regex I've given.